# Frustrating CSS Behavior with Cascading

Tags: jquery, css

I have a menu structure that is supposed to highlight each item as it is rolled over , and then some menu items expand downward into dropdown menus when clicked. The behavior works okay, but the problem is this.

Within the `<li class="dropdown">`, the styles of the a: tags are overriding anything I am specifying. Even if my style comes afterwards.

I can 'force' it to work with the "!important" flag placed on EVERY single element, but I really don't want to go that route. The 'subnav' class is the style that should be **visible** when clicking one of the parent menu items of the dropdown menu. how can I get the subnav class to show properly, if the basic hyperlink anchor values forcefully override it all the time?

This uses jQuery 1.3

Script:

```
 <script type="text/javascript">
     $(document).ready(function () {

         $('.dropdown a').click(function () {
             $(this).addClass("subhover");
         });

         $("ul.topnav li a").click(function () {
             $(this).parent().find("ul.subnav").slideDown('fast').show();

             $(this).parent().hover(function () {
             }, function () {
                 $(this).parent().find("ul.subnav").slideUp('fast');
                 $(this).parent().find("a").removeClass("subhover");
             });
         });
     });
 </script>
```

HTML:

```
 <div id="membership">
  <div class="container">
   <div class="container-inner">
    <ul id="options" class="topnav">
     <li><a href="#">Mail</a></li>
     <li><a href="#">Profile</a></li>
     <li><a href="#">Settings</a></li>
     <li class="dropdown">
      <a href="#">Membership</a>
      <ul class="subnav">
       <li>Item</li>
      </ul>
     </li>
    </ul>
   </div>
  </div>
 </div>
```

CSS:

```
#membership {
 font-size: 11px;
 font-weight: bold;
 height: 41px;
 font-family: Tahoma;
 color: #fff;
 position: relative;
}

 #membership .container-inner {
  border-color: #1D4088 #1D4088;
  border-style: solid solid none;
  font-size: 11px;
  height: 30px;
  margin-left: 180px;
  padding-left: 10px;
  padding-right: 6px;
  position: relative;
  top: 10px;
 }

  #membership a {
   color: #FFFFFF;
   display: inline-block;
   font-weight: bold;
   height: 22px;
   padding: 8px 16px 0;
   text-decoration: none;
   border-color: transparent;
   border-style: solid;
   border-width: 1px 1px 0px 1px;

  }


  #membership a:hover, #membership a:focus{
   outline:medium none;
  }

  #membership ul {
   list-style-type: none;
  }

   #membership ul li {
    padding: 0 3px 0 5px;
   }

   #membership ul li.active, #membership ul li.active a {
   }

   #membership #options {
    list-style: none outside none;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    position: absolute;
    right: 0;
    top: 0;
   }
   #membership #options li {
    float: left;
   }

   #membership .dropdown {
    float: right;
    position: relative;
   }

   #membership .dropdown ul
   {
       background: none repeat scroll 0 0 #FFFFFF;
       border-color: #333333 #333333 #333333;
       border-style: solid;
       border-width: 1px 2px 2px;
       display: none;
       margin-right: 2px;
       margin-top: -1px;
       min-width: 200px;
       padding: 10px 0 5px;
       position: absolute;
       right: 0;
       top: 100%;
   }


   #membership .dropdown a {
    border-color: transparent;
       border-style: solid;
       border-width: 1px 1px 0px 1px;
       height: 22px;
       position: relative;

    display: inline-block;
    font-weight: bold;
    height: 22px;
    padding: 8px 16px 0;
    text-decoration: none;
   }


   .subhover{
    background-color: #FFFFFF;
    color: #333333;
    border-color: #333333 #333333 #333333;
    border-style: solid;
    border-width: 1px 1px 0px 1px;
    height: 22px;
    position: relative;
    padding-right: 16px;
   }
```

Comment: I'm sorry, but: what's the **question** here?

Comment: "the styles of the a: tags are overriding anything I am specifying. Even if my style comes afterwards." What do you mean by afterwards?

Comment: how can I get the subnav class to show properly, if the basic hyperlink anchor values forcefully override it all the time?

Comment: I understand that css renders in the order in which things appear. So theoretically, putting the .subnav class last should make it render ontop of any other styles that it shares properties with, correct?

Comment: @Stacey, not necessarily. If there is a parent > child relationship, the style will "cascade" down, like in "cascading style sheet".

Comment: @Stacey, assigning the class later in the code doesn't mean it will override previosuly assigned style properties, it depends how you structure the classes in your stylesheet.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm beginning to see the problem, "`#membership .dropdown a`" supersedes "`.subnav`" on `<A>` elements, unless you specify the class as "`a.subnav`".

Answer (score 2):

The styles applied to "#membership a" correctly cascade to child `<a>` elements. To prevent this, remove any styles that you don't want to cascade from it, or if you want to apply nothing, give it a class name, like so: #membership a.whatever".

Comment: I DO want them to get applied. But when .subhover is applied via addClass, then .subhover should OVERRIDE it. That's the problem. It isn't. .subhover is just being ignored.

Comment: Stacey, try declaring the subhover class like so: #membership .dropdown a.subhover {CSS HERE}

Comment: Thank you all so much. This has been bothering me all day.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that #id-definitions have more importance than .class-definitions. But !important-definitions are even more important :-)

Add an !important to the style definitions which should not be overwritten. eg:

```
.subhover{
    background-color: #FFFFFF !important;
    color: #333333 !important;
    border-color: #333333 #333333 #333333 !important;
    border-style: solid !important;
    border-width: 1px 1px 0px 1px !important;
    height: 22px !important;
    position: relative !important;
    padding-right: 16px !important;
   }
```

edit: ja, i know it doesn't look nice :&

Comment: subnav exists only for jquery to link into.